# Does anyone have the preceding declaration before Tikkun HaKlali?

Tags: tefilla, internet, tehilim-psalms, breslov

I know the specific Tehillim to recite for Tikkun HaKlali, but I'm looking for the Hebrew text (with nikkudos) of the declaration before and Reb Noson's prayer that follows the Tehillim. Is this available somewhere online?

Comment: http://tk.r-inv.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all interested, I've typeset the entire thing to make it a bit easier on the eyes. I used the text available at [alonolam.com/tikun_haklali.htm](http://alonolam.com/tikun_haklali.htm) and simply made it look a lot better.

If anyone would like to proof-read it, it's available at [myorthodoxlife.com/sefer/tikkunhaklali/](http://myorthodoxlife.com/sefer/tikkunhaklali/). I'd like to improve it in a few ways still, such as removing the nikkud from Hashem, adding nikkud in the few places where it's lacking, etc. If anyone has any comments or concerns, please let me know.

The source code is available on GitHub at [github.com/rfkrocktk/tikkun-haklali](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/tikkun-haklali). Feel free to fork it and suggest changes.

Comment: I gather you had alonolam's permission....

Comment: Just asking for it now :-X

Answer (score 3):

http://www.briskodesh.org/PDF/tikkun-intro.pdf

That website has the psalms too.  The typeface isn't good. The original text is on the Breslover site which doesn't have niqudot.

(Found looking for Tikkun Olam of Rebbe Nachman)

Answer (score 3):

Here with Nikud

http://www.alonolam.com/tikun_haklali.htm

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found one in the app: Sefaria.

Comment: This would be more helpful with a specific link (you can do so easily when looking at Sefaria from a browser)